# Ignore .git folder in sub folder

Tags: git

Is it possible to add a sub folder with a .git folder to a repo, without Git treating it like a submodule? I've tried different methods to ignore that .git folder, but nothing this far has worked.

I have tried in /.gitignore:

```
/vendor/**/.git/
```

..and in /vendor/.gitignore:

```
.git/
```

The .git folder I want to ignore is in /vendor/foo/bar/.

Comment: .git/ is automatically ignored by git

Comment: Can you clarify what you're wanting? Are you sure it's not your Git GUI client erroneously treating a subfolder with a `.git` directory as a submodule? Which Git client are you using?

Comment: Twelve google searches later, Vinay Prajapati provides the answer I'm looking for in the comments.

Answer (score 9):

You can do this by directly adding some (any) internal content first. Git detects submodules by encountering the `.git` entry when searching a newly-encountered directory, but if you give it an actual path to look for inside that directory it doesn't search.

So

```
git add path/to/some/submodule/file     # bypass initial search that detects .git
git add path/to/some/submodule          # now git's index has it as ordinary dir
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use **git hooks** to achieve what you want. Thinking out of the box, you could create a **pre-commit** hook that renames the **.git** directory of your included project, eg. to ".git2", add all files in the latter project except the ".git2" directory, commit all, push it and finally use **post-commit hook** to rename ".git2" folder back to ".git" in your module.

1) Create **pre-commit** file under **.git/hooks/** of your **root** repo with contents:

```
#!/bin/sh
mv "vendor/foo/bar/.git" "vendor/foo/bar/.git2"

git rm --cached vendor/foo/bar
git add vendor/foo/bar/*
git reset vendor/foo/bar/.git2
```

2) Create **post-commit** file under **.git/hooks/** also with contents:

```
#!/bin/sh
mv "vendor/foo/bar/.git2" "vendor/foo/bar/.git"
```

3) Change a file in your repo and finally:

```
git commit -a -m "Commit msg"
git push
```

[My Original answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48649409/4448410)

Comment: Thanks for this. It inspired a husky-based solution.

Answer (score 0):

Your question intrigued me so I tried it:

```
$ cd /tmp
$ git init foo
Initialized empty Git repository in /private/tmp/foo/.git/
$ cd foo
$ git init bar
Initialized empty Git repository in /private/tmp/foo/bar/.git/
$ cd bar
$ echo "this is bar" > bar.txt
$ git add bar.txt
$ git commit -m "initial commit"
[master (root-commit) c9d6507] initial commit
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
 create mode 100644 bar.txt
$ cd ..
$ pwd
/tmp/foo
$ git status
On branch master

No commits yet

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

        bar/

nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
$ git add bar
$ git commit -m "parent initial commit"
[master (root-commit) b23e106] parent initial commit
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
 create mode 100644 bar/bar.txt
$ echo "baz" > bar/.git/baz.txt
$ git status
On branch master
nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

As per your question, `/tmp/foo` is a Git repository. And with respect to `/tmp/foo`, `/tmp/foo/bar` is a subdirectory which itself has a `.git` directory.

As you can see, the parent `foo` repository totally ignored the `bar/.git` subdirectory and I didn't even need a `.gitignore` file.

And there's no way Git treats a path containing a `.git` folder as a submodule without having it registered in the `.gitmodules` file.

Comment: I could have make it a comment but I couldn't have elaborated on the exact steps I used to come to my conclusion. So here it is as an answer

Comment: Your transcript doesn't match my expectation nor the git docs,and I can't reproduce it myself.  What version of Git are you running this on?  I've tried 2.16 and 2.12 and 2.10 so far.

Comment: `git version 2.16.2` on MacOS

Comment: I can reproduce it with `2.16.2` on Linux

Answer (score 0):

As in [jthill answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49203257/6603717), you can add any item from subdirectory with `.git` and it will be treated as subdirectory instead of sub-module.

But if you already registered this subdirectory as sub-module that has `.git` you have to first remove that sub-module but leave it in your working tree - `git rm --cached a/submodule`.

**More info on:** [How do I remove a submodule?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16162000/6603717)

Then you can repeat steps from [jthill answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49203257/6603717).

From my research there is no way to stop treating `.git` folder as sub-module. So the best solution that I can think of right now is to have `bash` or any similar script that you can run in any folder in console. It should find any subfolders that have `.git` and attempt to add any file from that folder to the main `.git`, so it would stop treating them as sub-modules.

**Source of code below:** [Bash script to automatically convert git submodules to regular files](https://ben.lobaugh.net/blog/202883/bash-script-to-automatically-convert-git-submodules-to-regular-files)

```
#!/bin/bash

# Get a list of all the submodules
submodules=($(git config --file .gitmodules --get-regexp path | awk '{ print $2 }'))

# Loop over submodules and convert to regular files
for submodule in "${submodules[@]}"
do  
   echo "Removing $submodule"
   git rm --cached $submodule # Delete references to submodule HEAD
   rm -rf $submodule/.git* # Remove submodule .git references to prevent confusion from main repo
   git add $submodule # Add the left over files from the submodule to the main repo
   git commit -m "Converting submodule $submodule to regular files" # Commit the new regular files!
done

# Finally remove the submodule mapping
git rm.gitmodules
```

Remember to always commit/backup changes before trying new scripts to prevent any work/data loss.

Answer (score 0):

While it is true `.git` is automatically ignored, the main repo will treat  `/vendor/foo/bar` as a gitlink (special entry in the main repo index), and not as regular files.

A trick would simply to *move* `bar/.git` *outside* the main repo:

- `vendor/foo/bar` would be treated as a regular sub-folder, to be added to the main repo if need be.
- the bar repo can at any time detect changes and make commit if you preceded your `git` command with `GIT_DIR=/path/to/bar/.git git ...`

For instance:

```
cd /path/to/main/repo/vendor/foo/bar
GIT_DIR=/path/to/bar/.git git status
GIT_DIR=/path/to/bar/.git git add .
GIT_DIR=/path/to/bar/.git git commit -m "changes to bar"
GIT_DIR=/path/to/bar/.git git push
```

Comment: Alternative syntax: `git --git-dir=/path/to/bar/.git status`

Answer (score 0):

You can use Git excludes for this.

First, create a .gitexclude file:

```
$ echo "vendor/*/.git" >> .gitexclude
```

Then add this file to your Git config as a source of exclusions:

```
$ git config core.excludesFile .gitexclude
```

Now you can add files and Git doesn't offer to add them as submodules:

```
$ git add vendor
$
```

You can verify that a file is indeed "invisible" to Git with `git check-ignore`:

```
$ git check-ignore vendor/foo/.git
vendor/foo/.git
$ git check-ignore vendor/foo/bar.txt
$
```

Reference: 
man git-add(1)
man git-check-ignore(1)

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried wildcards?

```
**/vendor/.git/
```