# Git ignore .git folder

Tags: php, git, composer-php, gitignore, vendor

I have a php project that uses composer for package management. One of the packages is another project belonging to the same repo. I have a need to commit my entire vendor folder, but I want to ignore the .git folder in the sub-project so that it doesn't get treated like a submodule.

So far I have had no success. Things I've already tried:

vendor/.git

vendor/**/.git/

google search

stack overflow search

---

Here's what the sub-project folder looks like in GitLab. Instead of the files, it's just some kind of reference.

[image]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3240881/git-can-i-suppress-listing-of-modified-content-dirty-submodule-entries-in-sta

Comment: That would be great, except I'm not using any of the packages as submodules. In fact that is what I'm specifically trying to avoid.

Comment: how about just ```.git``` in ```.gitignore```

Comment: That might work, but it would ignore every .git dir. I'd like to ignore .git for just one particular dir.

Comment: *.git should work !

Comment: So you have 2 git repositories, and the second is a sub-project of the first?

Comment: I use exactly same stack (php, composer, gitlab). But why commit vendor directory. You can always work around this. I found this necessary where some vendor directories need to be symlink in production machine which is read-only. If you're also using autoload feature of composer then tracking vendor triggers multiple changes(vendor/composer/autoload*files).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23362967/how-to-tell-git-to-ignore-git-sub-modules

Answer (score 3):

It looks like git automatically ignores .git folders in subfolders of root repository.

```
(master)[/tmp]  
$ mkdir test_root
(master)[/tmp]  
$ git init test_root
Initialized empty Git repository in /tmp/test_root/.git/
(master)[/tmp]  
$ cd test
test/      test_root/ 
(master)[/tmp]  
$ cd test_root/
(master)[/tmp/test_root]  (master) 
$ ls
(master)[/tmp/test_root]  (master) 
$ git init test_child
Initialized empty Git repository in /tmp/test_root/test_child/.git/
(master)[/tmp/test_root]  (master) 
$ git status
On branch master

Initial commit

nothing to commit (create/copy files and use "git add" to track)
(master)[/tmp/test_root]  (master) 
$ touch test_root_file
(master)[/tmp/test_root]  (master) 
$ cd test_child/
(master)[/tmp/test_root/test_child]  (master) 
$ ls
(master)[/tmp/test_root/test_child]  (master) 
$ touch test_child_file
(master)[/tmp/test_root/test_child]  (master) 
$ cd ..
(master)[/tmp/test_root]  (master) 
$ git status
On branch master

Initial commit

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

    test_child/
    test_root_file

nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
(master)[/tmp/test_root]  (master) 
$ git add test_child/test_child_file 
(master)[/tmp/test_root]  (master) 
$ git status
On branch master

Initial commit

Changes to be committed:
  (use "git rm --cached <file>..." to unstage)

    new file:   test_child/test_child_file

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

    test_root_file

(master)[/tmp/test_root]  (master) 
$ cd test_child/
(master)[/tmp/test_root/test_child]  (master) 
$ git status
On branch master

Initial commit

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

    test_child_file

nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
(master)[/tmp/test_root/test_child]  (master) 
$ git --version
git version 1.9.1
$ git add test_root_file 
(master)[/tmp/test_root]  (master) 
$ git status
On branch master

Initial commit

Changes to be committed:
  (use "git rm --cached <file>..." to unstage)

    new file:   test_child/test_child_file
    new file:   test_root_file

(master)[/tmp/test_root]  (master) 
$ git commit -m'1 commit'
[master (root-commit) 4d4b695] 1 commit
 2 files changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
 create mode 100644 test_child/test_child_file
 create mode 100644 test_root_file
(master)[/tmp/test_root]  (master) 
$ git show
commit 4d4b69589bf4f471c3c784f95f447d2a40ee6d7d
Author: Evgenii Shchemelev
Date:   Wed Jan 6 09:20:03 2016 +0200

    1 commit

diff --git a/test_child/test_child_file b/test_child/test_child_file
new file mode 100644
index 0000000..e69de29
diff --git a/test_root_file b/test_root_file
new file mode 100644
index 0000000..e69de29
```

Comment: Hmm. When I commit and push as normal, the sub-project shows up in the repo as a reference, while other packages (from packagist) show up as files. However if I manually delete the .git dir from my sub-project before committing, then all the files show up like expected. Maybe there's a better way than trying to ignore the .git dir?

Comment: Actually, idea of ignoring git folder looks wrong. Should be other way definitely. I've tried commit with conditions you described - everything working right. There is no references in commit. May be your packages actually are soft links in your file system?

Comment: @YevgeniyShchemelev try your test when the `.git` subdirectory houses information for a populated git repo.

Answer (score 3):

You can use **git hooks** to achieve what you want. Thinking out of the box, you could use **pre-commit** hook to rename the **.git** directory of your included project, eg. to ".git2", add all files in the latter project except the ".git2" directory, commit all, push it and finally use **post-commit hook** to rename ".git2" folder back to ".git" in your module.

1) Create **pre-commit** file under **.git/hooks/** of your **root** repo with contents:

```
#!/bin/sh
mv "vendor/modulename/.git" "vendor/modulename/.git2"

git rm --cached vendor/modulename
git add vendor/modulename/*
git reset vendor/modulename/.git2
```

2) Create **post-commit** file under **.git/hooks/** also with contents:

```
#!/bin/sh
mv "vendor/modulename/.git2" "vendor/modulename/.git"
```

3) Change a file in your repo and finally:

```
git commit -a -m "Commit msg"
git push
```

Comment: Thanks for this! Renaming the `.git` dir seems to be the only valid solution. It would be so much easier if git allowed adding `.git/` to `.gitignore` to make nested repos work...

Answer (score 2):

For me this looks like a design error:

If you load a second project from the same repository as dependency, this project should be moved to a different repository.

And **inside** the vendor Directory place another .gitignore file with

```
# Ignore Git here
.git

# But not these files...
!.gitignore
```

Comment: This doesn't work with `git 2.19.2` on my machine. Git still complains about subrepos, when I run `git add -A` in the parent repo.

Answer (score 0):

The entire `vendor` folder should be ignored, not just the `.git` sub-directories. Which packages are used are stored in `composer.json` and `composer.lock` which are what you check into version control.

See: https://getcomposer.org/doc/faqs/should-i-commit-the-dependencies-in-my-vendor-directory.md

If you want to create a reusable package as part of your project, you have two options:

## A) Use Composer to handle another repo

Add to `composer.json`...

```
{
    "repositories": [
        {
            "url": "https://github.com/l3pp4rd/DoctrineExtensions.git",
            "type": "git"
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "gedmo/doctrine-extensions": "~2.3"
    }
}
```

## B) Use a 2nd packages directory

You can create a `packages` directory and add it to your autoload paths. This will let you use a single Git repo for all the code (if you want to use two repos, you can use a Git submodule)

Add to `composer.json`...

```
"autoload": {
    "classmap": ["packages"]
}
```

Comment: This is a valid answer. OP stated they are using PHP, and what they are trying to achieve indicates a design error.

Answer (score 0):

For me, the most simple solution is using composer hooks.
Your package treated as submodule is because there is exist `.git` folder, then you just need to delete it.

composer.json

```json
"scripts": [
    "post-autoload-dump":  [
        "rm -rf vendor/webdriver/.git"
    ]
]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to ignore nested submodule totally, what you can do (below I will assume your nested repo is called "vendor/")

1. inside `vendor/` rename `.git` folder to `.git_`
2. in parent `.gitignore` file add: `/vendor/.git_/`
3. `/vendor/.git_/` will be ignored and you can add and commit other nested files and folders.
4. in `vendor/` rename `.git_` to `.git`
5. in parent `.gitignore` change `/vendor/.git_/` to `/vendor/.git/`

Now the `/vendor/.git/` is ignored and all other `vendor/` files and folders are committed.

I have done this several times and I think there may be easier way to do it but I have forgotten how. Anyway this works.

Answer (score -2):

To not treat sub folder as a submodule, delete the `.git` folder. So that you won't see a folder with `@number` in the website. If you want to update the submodule. You can create a script like the following written in `Shell`

update.sh

```
git clone <url> <subfolder that you won't treat it as a module>
rm -rf <subfolder>/.git/
git add <subfolder>
git commit -m "Updated module"
```

update.bat

```
git clone <url> <subfolder>
rmdir /s /q <subfolder>\.git
git add <subfolder>
git commit -m "Updated module"
```

I believe this is the best way to avoid `@number` in GitLab

You can refer my [GitHub repository](https://github.com/TravorLZH/subgitrepotest) created for answering this question.